# Задача на выбор коллекции

Tags: java, коллекции

Подскажите. (код - индекс массы тела)
Как организовать через LinkedList ?

```
public class BMIColletction {
    LinkedList<Float> limits;
    HashMap<Float, String> messages;

    public BMIColletction() {
        limits = new LinkedList<>();
        messages = new HashMap<>();
    }

    void addNewParam(float limit, String message) {
        limits.add(limit);
        messages.put(limit, message);
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BMIColletction bmicol = new BMIColletction();
        bmicol.addNewParam(16.0f, "Выраженный дефицит массы тела");
        bmicol.addNewParam(30.0f, "Избыточная масса тела (предожирение)");
        bmicol.addNewParam(40.0f, "Очень резкое ожирение");
        System.out.println(bmicol.messages);
        System.out.println(bmicol.limits);
        System.out.println(bmicol.checkIndex(35));
    }

    String checkIndex(double x) {
        for (Float limit : limits) {
            if (between(x, this.prev, this.next))
//непонятное место

        }
    }


    static boolean between(double x, double from, double to) {
        return (x > from) && (x <= to);
    }
}


//     if (between(bmi, Double.MIN_VALUE, 16.0f))
//    result = "Выраженный дефицит массы тела";
//        else if (between(bmi, 16.0f, 18.5f))
//    result = "Недостаточная (дефицит) масса тела";
//        else if (between(bmi, 18.5f, 25.0f))
//    result = "Норма";
//        else if (between(bmi, 25.0f, 30.0f))
//    result = "Избыточная масса тела (предожирение)";
//        else if (between(bmi, 30.0f, 35.0f))
//    result = "Ожирение";
//        else if (between(bmi, 35.0f, 40.0f))
//    result = "Ожирение резкое";
//        else if (between(bmi, 40.0f, Double.MAX_VALUE))
//    result = "Очень резкое ожирение";
```

**Вопрос:**
Пытаюсь проверить некоторый элемент на его место в linkedList, с помощью next/prev.
Как это сделать? Т.е. какими командами/полями оперировать ?
Вроде есть вложенный класс Node, но этот момент не очень понятен.

Comment: Мне кажется, тут нужен какой то контекст. Если интервалов очень много, то с точки зрения алгоритмов есть смысл использовать [IntervalTree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_tree). Если вам любую коллекцию привязать надо, то вы может свой класс создать с интервалом и хоть в ArrayList его засунуть, потом ходить по ArrayList и проерять каждый интервал.

Comment: @tym32167 , не подскажите, еще немного?
Изменил постановку вопроса и немного переписал код.
Вопрос в проблеме оперированием next/prev. Что куда дописать?
И вообще, правильно ли я пытаюсь делать метод checkIndex?

Answer (score 1):

Насколько я понял, в вашем случае это не совсем диапазон. Точнее диапазон специфический. Его особенность состоит в том, что это по сути шкала, разделенная на части. Это упрощает задачу. Полагаю, что в данном случае вам вполне подойдет обычная коллекция типа ключ - значение. Использовать ее придется нетипично, ведь искать нужно будет итератором, но в силу того, что в коллекция не будет содержать большого количества элементов, это не имеет большого значения. Я создал экземпляр класса Properties прямо в методе main, разумеется, это только для демонстрации. Вам предстоит вынести это в файл свойств, подгрузить его и передать в конструктор класса (можно добавить метод для загрузки свойст).

```
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Properties;
import java.util.TreeMap;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class BmiEstimation {    
    
    private final Map<Integer, String> bmiMap;

    public BmiEstimation(Properties properties) {
        this.bmiMap = properties.entrySet().stream()
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                        k->convertBmi(Double.valueOf(k.getKey().toString())), 
                        v->String.valueOf(v.getValue()), 
                        (o1, o2) -> o1, TreeMap::new));
    }
    
    public String bmiInterpretation(double bmi) {
        final Integer bmiInt = convertBmi(bmi);        
        for (Integer bmiKey : bmiMap.keySet()) {
            if (bmiKey > bmiInt) return bmiMap.get(bmiKey);
        }
        return "ERROR";
    }
    
    private Integer convertBmi(double bmi){
        return (int) bmi * 10;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Properties лучше загрузить из файла-свойств порядок данных не имеет значения, что обеспечивается конструктором
        Properties prop = new Properties();
        prop.put(16.0, "Выраженный дефицит массы тела");
        prop.put(25.0, "Норма");
        prop.put(18.5, "Недостаточная (дефицит) масса тела");
        
        BmiEstimation bmiEstimation = new BmiEstimation(prop);        
        System.out.println(bmiEstimation.bmiInterpretation(17));
    }
    
}
```